# Why can't ROS find this file?

Tags: navigation, rosparam, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#Error

```
error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [costmap_common_params.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I tried putting the files in the same folder as the launch file and that didn't work. Scanning around my hard drive I found the file located at `~/catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros/launch/azimut3/config/costmap_common_params.yaml`

What's going on here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241644/why-can%27t-ros-find-this-file?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `file` parameter to rosparam needs an absolute file name (technically it's relative to the working directory for roslaunch, but you shouldn't count on that).

You can give the file parameter an absolute path by using the `$(find pkg)` substitution to start with the absolute path to a package, and then use the path of the file within that package.

Since you're looking for the `config/costmap_common_params.yaml` file within the `azimut3` package, you can refer to that file relative to the azimut3 package:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find azimut3)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
```

for more substitutions and examples, have a look at the [roslaunch XML syntax documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-08-13**:
`ResourceNotFound: azimut3` so I found another copy of the file at `~/catkin_ws/install/share/rtabmap_ros/launch/config/costmap_common_params.yaml` and changed the file reference to `$(find rtabmap_ros)` but ROS is looking in `/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/rtabmap_ros/launch/config/` instead. ??

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2016-08-15**:
If you want to use the install location `~/catkin_ws/install/` you should source that setup.bash file. i.e. `source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-17**:
Can you find the `azimut3` package with `rospack find azimut3`? If you can't, you should figure out why and fix that. Perhaps there isn't a package.xml in your azimut3 package, or it doesn't have the right package name in it?